# How to set template in onepage/checkout/success

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am in trouble with the onepage/checkout/success page cause I want to set the root template from 2columns-right.phtml to 1column.phtml. Should not be a problem ...

I have got the default package with the base-theme and a custom-theme:

- frontend/base/default/
- frontend/default/custom/

First I tried to change the template in my local.xml

*frontend/default/custom/layout/local.xml*

```
<layout>
...
<checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
...
</layout>
```

Without any effects.

Then I tried to use a custom checkout.xml (same as above) without any effect again.
Also when I copy the whole content of base/default/layout/checkout.xml and change "only" the template-file, there are no effects.

I have cleanup/disabled all caches and uninstalled all non-standard plugins.

Magento is V. 1.7.0.2.

Any ideas?

--

`/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` => 2columns-left.phtml

`/default/custom/layout/checkout.xml` => 1column.phtml

Frontend/Browser => 2columns-right.phtml

Comment: Did you set your package and theme in the correct Configuration Scope for your store?

Comment: Package and theme is set in "Default Config" scope which is nowhere overwritten.

Comment: If you have `checkout.xml` copied to your custom theme then editing `/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` will have no effect.  Try editing the copy of checkout.xml that you copied to your own custom theme.

Comment: Still no effect. Have a look at the bottom of my question (updated).

Comment: Just for the heck of it, try editing `/default/default/layout/checkout.xml`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28107/discussion-between-seanbreeden-and-christian-moelders)

Comment: WTF! When I add `/default/default/layout/checkout.xml` it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Christian, You said yourself, Package and Theme is set in "Default Config" scope. When you place the file in /default/custom/layout/ you are placing the file in a different template folder. You can do one of two (three) things:

#### Change Design Settings

Under **System > Configuration > Design > Themes**, set **Templates**, **Skin**, and **Layout** to **"custom"**.

Refresh your cache and it should start using the folders /design/frontend/default/custom/...

#### Use Default/Default Theme Package

You can just edit the Default theme. You can copy the files over from "Base/Default" to "Default/Default" and set it to not overwrite any files, then move your files from "Default/Custom" and overwrite over the default folder. 
**Note:** This gets the job done, but isn't generally recommended. (Keep Reading ;D)

#### Change Design Settings and Use local.xml

Change your configuration as stated above. The most accepted way of changing the layout in Magento nowadays is to use **local.xml**. This would be located in your **Default/Custom/Layout/** folder. This one file will be where all your layout updates will be done, and you won't have to touch any core files in the process.

Some things you're used to doing will have to change, since you won't be editing the base files directly. The local.xml gets loaded last, so any adjustments made here shouldn't be overwritten. To accomplish what you're aiming to do, your local.xml might start off something like this:

#### local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>

    <checkout_onepage_failure>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_failure>

</layout>
```

You will have to adjust the way you remove things, it's no longer as simple as commenting out, deleting, or moving a line though.

#### Remove a Block Completely

To remove a block, get it's block name (or as="") and insert the below code in the appropriate reference.

```
<remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
```

#### Move a Block Elsewhere

Moving blocks around is a two parter, first you must **unsetChild** in the containing reference and **insert** the block in its new location. For example:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="insert">
        <!-- Name of Block -->
        <blockName>right.poll</blockName>
        <!-- Name of Adjacent Block -->
        <siblingName>left.newsletter<siblingName>
        <!-- Does it Come Before(0)? Or After(1)? Adjacent Block  -->
        <after>0</after>
    </action>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>right.poll</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Note:** Here, the **0** typically only applies to blocks where their phtml file contains a **echo $this->getChildHtml('')**. This means it is loading all referenced child blocks as listed in the xml.

Also note, the files that use the same function using the block name (e.g. **getChildHtml('top_links')**) will typically require you to clone that template file into your design (Default/Custom/Template/) and manually add **echo $this->getChildHtml('your_block_name')** where you wish your block to appear (after placing it in your local.xml).

That should get you started, there's plenty of good articles online and stack overflow is a good place for info as well.